# Stopping IOLoop if IOStream.connect does not work

Tags: python, tornado

I have a script that needs to connect asynchronously to a TCP server and send some data using TornadoWeb (3.2).

This is the short version:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.iostream
import socket

def main():
    def do_something():
        print 'doing something'
        stream.close()
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    stream = tornado.iostream.IOStream(s)
    stream.connect(("10.0.0.0", 80), do_something)

main()
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

If stream.connect fails I cannot close the IOLoop and the script just hangs.
First I thought that closing IOLoop just after stream.connect might work, but it actually closes the IOLoop before the connection takes place and exits the script.

Also, it seems I cannot try/except this, since stream.connect does not raise any exception in case of failure, but rather returns nothing:

```
# I stripped out the comments
def connect(self, address, callback=None, server_hostname=None):
    self._connecting = True
    try:
        self.socket.connect(address)
    except socket.error as e:
        if (e.args[0] != errno.EINPROGRESS and
                e.args[0] not in _ERRNO_WOULDBLOCK):
            gen_log.warning("Connect error on fd %d: %s",
                            self.socket.fileno(), e)
            self.close(exc_info=True)
            return
    self._connect_callback = stack_context.wrap(callback)
    self._add_io_state(self.io_loop.WRITE)
```

So, the main question is: How can I close IOLoop regardless if stream.connect works or not, but only after stream.connect does it's job?

Answer (score 1):

If the connection fails, the stream's close_callback will be called instead of the connect callback, so call stream.set_close_callback() before connect() to set up an error handler.

However, I recommend using coroutines instead of callbacks for code like this, which would look like:

```
import socket
import tornado.gen
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.iostream

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    stream = tornado.iostream.IOStream(s)
    try:
        yield stream.connect(('10.0.0.0', 80))
    except Exception as e:
        print("connection failed: %s" % e)
    print("doing something")
    stream.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(main)
```

Coroutines generally have simpler error handling and run_sync() ties the lifetime of the IOLoop to the lifetime of the main function.

Comment: I tried stream.set_close_callback(close_call) before stream.connect, but does not work (I guess that it does not enter the if inside the except). This is part of a bigger picture, so I would actually want to run this inside an IOLoop that is already running, instead of using run_sync.

Comment: Also, yielding stream.connect() raises exception all the time since it does not return anything (even when it works).

Comment: What version of Tornado are you using? Since 4.0 connect() returns a Future for use with yield. I don't know why set_close_callback wouldn't work; it should call at least one of the connect or close callbacks on any version of Tornado.

Comment: As I already mentioned in the question, I use version 3.2. If you look at the connect implementation you can see that it returns nothing (in both cases).

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that in the question. In that case I recommend upgrading, and then using the coroutine style. :) The close callback should still work, though. What sort of connection failure are you seeing? (what happens if you use an ordinary synchronous socket.connect?)

Comment: Upgrading at this point is not an option. The error is: "socket.error: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected". The problem is not the error(since this is just for testing and my server is up and running), but the fact that in case of server failure I will end up with tons of python processes that are hanging.

Comment: Hmm, the close callback should definitely fire in this case (since the error is not EINPROGRESS, EWOULDBLOCK, or equivalent). I'm not sure what's going on to prevent it.